# PHP using foreach on a sorted array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

Hi all I have an array I am storing timestamps in. I then sort them using `asort()` and then I want to go through each one with a `foreach` but I get an invalid argument supplied error here is what I have:

```
$sorted_dates = asort($dates_to_sort);
```

var_dump:

```
array(4) { [2]=> int(1512086400) [3]=> int(1512432000) [1]=> int(1513036800) [0]=> int(1514073600) }
```

Foreach:

```
foreach ($sorted_dates as $value) {
    echo "<br>".$value."<br>";
}
```

Error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Any idea how I can go through the array as I need to do more than echo it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`asort` returns a `boolean` and you can't iterate over a boolean!

```
// your code should be like
asort($dates_to_sort);
foreach ($dates_to_sort as $value) {
    echo "<br>".$value."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass `$dates_to_sort` to `foreach()` not `$sorted_dates`. Like:

```
foreach ($dates_to_sort as $value) {
    echo "<br>".$value."<br>";
}
```

Because [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) takes the input by reference and return `bool`. See:

> ```
> bool asort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

[`asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) will sort the array by reference, returning a boolean true/false if the sorting was successful or not.

```
asort($dates_to_sort);
foreach ($dates_to_sort as $value) {
    echo "<br>".$value."<br>";
}
```